Google Weather source different for Samsung phones vs Moto phones
I have a couple of Samsung phones (S23, A54) and a couple of Moto phones (G Stylus 2022, G Power 2023) and I noticed that the Google Weather app/widget shows different weather forecasts for the same location on the Samsung phones vs the Moto phones. When I scroll all the way down on the Samsung phones, it shows that Google uses "Google Weather" as the source, while on the Moto phones, it shows "weather.com".









Moto phones
Samsung phones



I notice the "Google Weather" forecasts are a lot more accurate than the "weather.com" forecasts.
Is there a way to change the Moto phones to use the same source as the Samsung phones?
